# Mongodb Index Suggestions

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

First time I am using mongodb, I need help with index suggestions. In my mongo database I have collection with nearly 15 million documents.Attached is json document.  The "playfields" is array of embedded documents . I frequently run following queries. The data  in value field is stored in different datatypes (string, int). My question is what is best index to add on this documents to cover below queries:

```
db.playfieldvalues.find({"playfields":{$elemMatch:{ID:"Play.NHL.NHLEventX", value: -47}}})
```

**Sample JSON Doc:**

```
{
  "Playid": "9dbc7763-7d47-44e9-8b11-e1ec864407bb",
  "Playfields": [
    {
      "ID": "XInfo_OffTeam",
      "Value": "Dallas",
      "TS": "201709291148408452"
    },
    {
      "ID": "XInfo_DefTeam",
      "Value": "Kansas",
      "TS": "201709291148456267"
    },
    {
      "ID": "XInfo_Period",
      "Value": 1,
      "TS": "201709291148456267"
    },
    {
      "ID": "XInfo_OffScore",
      "Value": 38,
      "TS": "201709291148456267"
    },
    {
      "ID": "XInfo_DefScore",
      "Value": 21,
      "TS": "201709291148456267"
    },
    {
      "ID": "XInfo_PlayAction",
      "Value": "Y",
      "TS": "201709291148456267"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your queries on `Playfields` always use the `$elemMatch` operator to address a pairing of `ID` and `Value` then creating a composite index on `Playfields.ID`, `Playfields.Value` sounds sensible:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "Playfields.ID": 1, "Playfields.Value": 1 })
```

But ... any index creation should probaby be accompanied by some empirical testing. Run your queries with `explain()` to understand whether your index is actually chosen and, if so, how selective it is:

```
db.playfieldvalues.find({ "playfields": { $elemMatch: { ID: "Play.NHL.NHLEventX", Value: -47 } } })
    .explain()
```

There are plenty of details [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) on the contents of the 'explain document' but the first things to check are:

- What index (if any) was chosen
- Number of keys examined
- Number of docs examined

Crudely speaking the closer 'keys examined' is to the number of docs returned the more index coverage you have achieved.

If your index has not been chosen by MongoDB then you should review the details provided by the explain plan on rejected plans and why they were rejected.

There is also the question of the cost of an index (in terms of impact on write times and index storage) so I'd suggest considering your non functional requirements - can your desired elapsed times be achieved without a dedicated index? If not, then you should proceed with empirical testing but be prepared to tweak your choice in reponse to what the `explain()` output tells you.

Comment: The milti key composite index looks working fine  for some queries.                
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "Playfields.ID": 1, "Playfields.Value": 1 })

Following query runs faster after adding index:

db.playfieldvalues.find(({playfields: {$elemMatch:{ID:"Play.NHL.NHLEventX" ,value: 58}}}))

Following  query with logical operators  runs very slow:

db.playfieldvalues.find({$and:[
  {playfields: {$elemMatch:{ID:"Play.NHL.NHLEventY" ,value: -38}}},
  {playfields: {$elemMatch:{ID:"Play.NHL.NHLEventX" ,value: 58}}}
  ]
})

Comment: Indeed ... you should proceed with empirical testing but be prepared to tweak your choice in reponse to what the explain() output tells you.